# spawn_link is starting an infinite loop, but does not return?

Tags: erlang, spawn

I have an init function which I call start_server:

```
start_server() ->
    spawn_link(game_loop(0,0)).
```

The purpose is to start a new process that begin to loop and waiting for someone to send a message there:

```
game_loop(X,Y) ->
receive
{move, left} ->
    tell_client(X+1,Y),
    game_loop(X+1,Y);

{move, right} ->
    tell_client(X-1,Y),
    game_loop(X-1,Y)
end.
```

My thaught was that start_server would return the Pid so that I could write something like this in the Erlang terminal:

```
> Server = server:start_server().
```

And then use the variable Server to handle the servers via functions like:

```
move_left(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {move, left}.
```

But that does not work since start_server() never returns, why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `spawn_link/1` takes a function as an argument. But in your code you dont pass a function into it:

```
start_server() ->
    spawn_link(game_loop(0,0)).
```

That sample means that the function `game_loop/2` will be called first and after it returns `spawn_link/1` will be called with an argument which is a result of calling of `game_loop/2`. But your function `game_loop/2` implements infinite loop so it will never returns and so `spawn_link/1` will never be called. If we even assume that `game_loop/2` returns it must return a function to call `spawn_link/1` properly, otherwise an exception will rise.

To do what you want you should pass `game_loop/2` as a function into `spawn_link/1`:

```
start_server() ->
    spawn_link(fun () -> game_loop(0,0) end).
```